# GWT ToggleButton Only Shows Text from UiBinder

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, togglebutton

I am trying to get the ToggleButton to show up. Currently only the text I specified for each button is rendering. Nothing is complaining, and within the UiHandler it sees the
ToggleButton's methods fine.

First I just added the button, but then also tried adding an upFace, but still nothing.

```
    <g:ToggleButton ui:field="myToggleButton" text="Button">
    </g:ToggleButton>
```

And corresponding UiField and UiHandler

```
@UiField
ToggleButton myToggleButton;

@UiHandler("myToggleButton")
void onPress(ClickEvent e){
    if(myToggleButton.getValue() == true){
    doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you examine this widget in a browser? Which CSS classes are applied to it? Do you have any other CSS classes that override them?

Comment: In the browser only the text specified in the text="Button" is showing up. At this stage in the project I am working on I have not defined any CSS. Maybe it is failing to load the default CSS for some reason?

Comment: You can check what CSS is loaded and which CSS rules are applied to this widget in your browser. In Chrome, you can use Inspect Element to open a console which shows you the selected element, its attributes and CSS.